# "Command Prompt Here" without shift key in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I want "Command Prompt Here" in right click menu for all folders but without having to hold shift key.

It was possible in earlier versions of windows, [like this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-command-prompt-here-always-display-for-folders-in-windows-vista) but it's not working anymore, in Windows 10.

Has this method changed in Windows 10? or is there another way to do this?

Comment: my favorite method to do this is just write "cmd" in the explorer adressbar, cmd will then open in the current folder.

Comment: @SimonS, you have my upvote, and a hundred more if I could...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [registry method](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-command-prompt-here-always-display-for-folders-in-windows-vista) actually has changed slightly, as I discovered tinkering with the registry.

There are now **two** locations that have the `Extended` key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd
```

The `\Background\shell` is newly added one and deleting the `Extended` key from that location is what worked for me.

Comment: Location #1 for when you right-click the desktop, or in a folder background (empty area). Location #2 applies when you right-click on a folder icon.

Comment: When I run Regedit as administrator, I can't change anything - I don't have permissions. Admin has full control over HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell, but read-only for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd, and it won't let me change the permissions.

Comment: @JeffDege Registry also has its own permissions (search "windows registry permissions") try tinkering with that.

Comment: It was necessary for me to rename the `HideBasedOnVelocityId` key as well.

Comment: Deleting the `Extended` key worked for me, but I also first changed permissions on the `cmd` tree items based on instructions here: https://www.windowscentral.com/add-open-command-window-here-back-context-menu-windows-10 These instructions were to make the option show up in the first place (when pressing shift).

Answer (score 3):

In the Latest Windows 10 - 1909 the only concerned location is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd`. And none of the answers explained how to deal with permissions before editing.

First, we need to change permissions for the regedit branch revealed above:

## 1- Right click **cmd** > Permission

[image]

## 2- Press "Advanced"

[image]

## 3- Press "Change" link on top

[image]

## 4- Input your user name (you can find yours by typing `%userprofile%` in run command or windows search), click check and ok

[image]

## 5- Check Replace Owner and press OK

[image]

## 6- Finally select your user **accounts** one by one and check full control (you may have more than 2)

[image]

At this point we can edit the keys and you only need to rename `Extended` to `_Extended_`. And rename `HideBasedOnVelocityId` to `ShowBasedOnVelocityId`

Your keys should look like..

[image]

Done! If you right click inside any folder "open command prompt here" should be there.